# Why is alertable line breaks not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `alertable.js` [plugin](https://github.com/claviska/jquery-alertable). When I try Line breaks it's not working.

I try:

```
$.alertable.confirm('Line1\nLine2').then(function() {
  //ok
}, function() {
  //not     
});
```

Comment: Please define "_do not work_".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you enter into `confirm` is what gets displayed as HTML. In HTML `\n` is not parsed as a line break, and thus is rendered normally.

Instead, you can use the HTML break tag `<br />` like so if you set the [`html` option](https://github.com/claviska/jquery-alertable#options) to true:

```
$.alertable.confirm('Line1<br />Line2', {
  html: true
}).then(function() {
  //ok
}, function() {
  //not     
});
```

See working example [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeKMPp)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the message option to `html` and insert a `<br/>` tag instead of `\n` for new line:

```
$.alertable.confirm('Line1 <br/> Line2', {
  html: true,
}).then(function() {
    //ok
}, function() {
    //not     
});
```

You can refer to the documentation here: https://github.com/claviska/jquery-alertable#options